# Prometheus cannot scrape kubernetes metrics

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus

I have setup a kubernetes cluster using kubeadm. I then deployed prometheus on it using the community helm charts.
I notice that prometheus cannot scrape metrics from the scheduler, etcd or the controller manager.

For example I see errors like this:

```
Get "https://192.168.3.83:10259/metrics": dial tcp 192.168.3.83:10259: connect: connection refused
```

The reason I get these errors is because there is in fact nothing listening on https://192.168.3.83:10259/metrics. This because kube-scheduler has --bind-address set to 127.0.0.1

One way I can fix this is by manually editing the manifest files in /etc/kubernetes/manifests, changin --bind-address to 0.0.0.0

When I do this prometheus is able to scrape those metrics.

However, is this the correct solution? I assume that those manifest files are actually managed by kubernetes itself, and that I should probably not directly edit those, and do something else. But what?

edit: I have since noticed that changes I make to the manifest files do indeed get overwritten when doing an upgrade. And now I have again lost the etcd and other metrics.

I must be missing something obvious here.

I though that maybe changing the "clusterconfiguration" configmap would do the trick. But if you can do this (and how you should do this) is not documented anywhere.

I have an out of the box kubernetes, and out of the box prometheus and it does not collect metrics. I cannot be the only one running in to this issue. Is there really no solution?

Comment: See [link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/expose-external-ip-address/) maybe it could help you

Answer (score 0):

### Exposing kube-scheduler, etcd or the kube-controller manager (and persisting the changes)

You *can* expose the metrics on 0.0.0.0 just as you have done by editing the configmap and then pulling those changes to each control plane node. These changes will then be persisted accross upgrades. For etcd this can also be done in another way which might preferrable (see further down)

**First step**: edit the configmap with the below command:

```
kubectl edit -n kube-system cm/kubeadm-config
```

Add/change the relevant bind addresses as described [here](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/docs/kube-prometheus-on-kubeadm.md), but for example for etcd like outline below:

```
kind: ClusterConfiguration
etcd:
  local:
    extraArgs:
      listen-metrics-urls: http://0.0.0.0:2381
```

**Second step**: ***NOTE:*** Please read [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-upgrade/#cmd-upgrade-node) to understand the upgrade command ***before*** applying it to any cluster you care about since it might also update  cluster component versions unless you just did an upgrade :)

For the changes to be reflected you thus need to run `kubeadm upgrade node` on each controlplane node (one at the time please..) This will bring down the affected pods (those to which you have made changes) and start a new instance with the metrics exposed. You can verify before & after with for example: `netstat -tulpn | grep etcd`

For etcd the default port in Prometheus is `2379` so it also need to be adjusted to `2381` as below in your prometheus value file:

```
kubeEtcd:
  service:
    port: 2381
    targetPort: 2381
```

Source to the above solution [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/204#issuecomment-1003558431)

### Accessing existing etcd metrics without exposing it further

For ETCD metrics there is a second, perhaps preferred way of accessing the metrics using the already exposed http***s*** metric endpoint on port 2379 (which requires authentication). You can verify this with Curl:

```
curl https://<your IP>:2379/metrics -k --cert /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --key /etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
```

For this to work we need to supply Prometheus with the correct certificates as a secret in kubernetes. Steps described [here](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/204#issuecomment-765155883) and outlined below:

Create a secret in the namespace where Prometheus is deployed.

```
kubectl -n monitoring create secret generic etcd-client-cert --from-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/ca.crt --from-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.crt --from-file=/etc/kubernetes/pki/etcd/healthcheck-client.key
```

add the following to your prometheus helm value file

```
prometheus:
  prometheusSpec:
    secrets: ['etcd-client-cert']

kubeEtcd:
  serviceMonitor:
   scheme: https
   insecureSkipVerify: false
   serverName: localhost
   caFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/etcd-client-cert/ca.crt
   certFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/etcd-client-cert/healthcheck-client.crt
   keyFile: /etc/prometheus/secrets/etcd-client-cert/healthcheck-client.key
```

Prometheus should now be able to access the https endpoint with the certificates that we mounted in the secret. I would say this is the preferred way for etcd since we don't expose the open http endpoint further.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I deployed to my setup on AWS consisting of three nodes of which master (control plane) and private worker were int he private subnet and the public worker node in the public subnet. I create a **HAproxy** from the [source](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/issues/913) and made modifications for a pass-through configuration to get it to work:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: metrics-proxy-master
data:
  haproxy.cfg: |
    defaults
      mode http
      timeout connect 5000ms
      timeout client 5000ms
      timeout server 5000ms
      default-server maxconn 10

    frontend kube-controller-manager
      bind ${NODE_IP}:10257
      mode tcp
      option tcplog
      http-request deny if !{ path /metrics }
      default_backend kube-controller-manager
    backend kube-controller-manager
      mode tcp
      server kube-controller-manager 127.0.0.1:10257 check

    frontend kube-scheduler
      bind ${NODE_IP}:10259
      mode tcp
      option tcplog
      http-request deny if !{ path /metrics }
      default_backend kube-scheduler
    backend kube-scheduler
      mode tcp
      server kube-scheduler 127.0.0.1:10259 check

    frontend etcd
      bind ${NODE_IP}:2381
      http-request deny if !{ path /metrics }
      default_backend etcd
    backend etcd
      server etcd 127.0.0.1:2381

---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: metrics-proxy-master
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: metrics-proxy-master
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: metrics-proxy-master
    spec:
      hostNetwork: true
      serviceAccountName: default
      nodeSelector:
        node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane: ""
      tolerations:
        - effect: NoSchedule
          key: node-role.kubernetes.io/control-plane
          operator: Exists
      containers:
        - name: haproxy
          image: haproxy:2.2.8
          env:
            - name: NODE_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  apiVersion: v1
                  fieldPath: status.hostIP
          ports:
            - name: kube-ctrl-mgr  # Port names are limited to 15 characters
              containerPort: 10257
            - name: kube-scheduler
              containerPort: 10259
            - name: etcd
              containerPort: 2381
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/local/etc/haproxy
              name: haproxy-config
      volumes:
        - configMap:
            name: metrics-proxy-master
          name: haproxy-config
```

Then applied it `kubectl apply -f haproxy.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

For those using minikube for testing - 
Not enough rep or I'd comment on apisen's answer, which works for me. But I am using minikube, so I had to adjust the minikube start statement adding the following to expose etcd metrics (which is equivalent to the update in `kubectl edit -n kube-system cm/kubeadm-config`). 
 The last line is the relevant addition (which is different than I found here on the official docs - [prometheus operator - kube-prometheus](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/main/README.md#minikube)

```bash
minikube start --kubernetes-version=v1.23.0 \
--memory=6g \
--bootstrapper=kubeadm \
--extra-config=kubelet.authentication-token-webhook=true \
--extra-config=kubelet.authorization-mode=Webhook \
--extra-config=scheduler.bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
--extra-config=controller-manager.bind-address=0.0.0.0 \
--extra-config=etcd.listen-metrics-urls=http://0.0.0.0:2381
```

Hope this helps